# Displaying the web site table elements by clicking them in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have assigment in which I have to display some table rows in chrome extension by clicking on the row. I have been searching on answers for past two days and it isn't clear to me. I have popup.html, popup.js, background.js and myscript.js, but it is hard to me to make connection from web page to extension with message passing. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code!

Comment: I have my html page with table (bc it should work on that exactly  page), manifest.json, popup.html with just one <h4> tag that is now empty and I have been trying from myscript.js which is declared in manifest just simple chrome.runtime.sendMessage("hello");, and in backgroun.js : chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse){
    alert(response);
});
I found that in some tutorial to start with,but it doesn't work and it isn't even communication with popup.js, only background. Don't know what to do next